# How can I make the parallel static and dynamic version of this two loops?

Tags: c, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I would like to know how to obtain the same result when I execute the parallel version of this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define N 10000
int MAT[N][N], B[N], C[N];
void main ()
{
    int i, j, x = 0;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) 
    {
        B[i] = i % 3;
        for (j=0; j<N; j++) MAT[i][j] = (i + j) % 7 - 2;
    }
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        C[i] = 0;
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
        for (j=0; j<N; j++) 
            C[i] += MAT[i][j] * B[j];
        x += C[i];
    }
    printf ("\n x = %d\n", x);
}
```

The result must be 99990002 but I obtain different results with 2, 4, 8, 16 and 32 threads. And I must to obtain the same result with the static and dynamic parallel version with all that different number of threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simples solution is to parallelize only the outer loop:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define N 10000
int MAT[N][N], B[N];
void main ()
{
    int i, j, x = 0;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        B[i] = i % 3;
        for (j=0; j<N; j++) 
            MAT[i][j] = (i + j) % 7 - 2;
    }
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 1) reduction(+:x)
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        for (j=0; j<N; j++) 
            x += MAT[i][j] * B[j];
    printf ("\n x = %d\n", x);
}
```

The dynamic version would be as follows:

```
 #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1) reduction(+:x)
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    for (j=0; j<N; j++) 
        x += MAT[i][j] * B[j];
  printf ("\n x = %d\n", x);
```

Apart from that, your code has the following issues:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
 for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    C[i] = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
```

Your inner loop is not actually distributing the iterations among threads as you might have wanted. Because you added the `parallel` clause again, and assuming that you have nested parallelism disabled, which by default it is, each of the threads created in the outer `parallel region` will execute "sequentially" the code within that region, namely:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
for (j=0; j<N; j++) 
     C[i] += MAT[i][j] * B[j];
x += C[i];
}
```

The other problem is that you have a *race condition* during the update of the variable `x`, which can be solved by adding the OpenMP `reduction` clause into the `parallel for` (*i.e.,* `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 1) reduction(+:x)`). Lastly, since now we reduce the variable `x`, the array `C` is no longer anymore.

If you *really* want to parallelize both loops simultaneously, you need to use OpenMP `collapse` clause, and adapt your code accordingly, for instance:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define N 10000
int MAT[N][N], B[N];
void main ()
{
    int i, j, x = 0;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        B[i] = i % 3;
        for (j=0; j<N; j++)
            MAT[i][j] = (i + j) % 7 - 2;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 1) collapse(2) reduction(+:x)
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        for (j=0; j<N; j++)
            x += MAT[i][j] * B[j];
    printf ("\n x = %d\n", x);
}
```